# How to identify merge modules (.msm files)?

Tags: windows-installer, file-type, merge-module

Many file types can be identified by their magic number, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

I want to tell if a file is a Microsoft Merge Module (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa369820(v=vs.85).aspx))

Do Microsoft Merge Modules (.msm files) have a magic number? 
If not, how can I programmatically find out if a file is a Merge Module?
I do not want to rely on the file extension (.msm).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if merge modules have a magic number, but if you are looking to somehow inspect a generic file and determine if it's a .msm or not, maybe you could do something like this:

1. Take a look at the vbscripts here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372865(v=vs.85).aspx
2. Write a custom vb script to attempt to call OpenDatabase() on the file to see if it's a valid installer database file.
3. Use WiRunSQL.vbs to run some SQL statement on the file and check to see if it has the table "Property" with a value for "ProductName".

   a. If so, it's a .msi

   b. If not, it's a .msm

Comment: Good hint to the Microsoft functions. What SQL statement do I need to run?

Comment: I managed to do it in python using the module `msilib`. I will post my complete solution below.

Comment: MSM is the compound files like MSI, DOC, PPT, XLS, etc. You can try to parse the file structure and then search for the stream "MergeModule".